# Git Diff responds less -r: less: command not found

Tags: git, macos, terminal

I've read through everything on the site that I could find and nothing answered my question.

I've tried both in detached head state and after running `git checkout master`, but when I enter `git diff` I receive the response `less -r: less: command not found`

I'm extremely new to git and I'm not sure why this is happening. I'm in a file that 100% has Git attached to it because I was able to access it yesterday. Perhaps I've accessed the file the wrong way today?

I'm using Terminal on a Mac.

Thanks so much for any help you can give me.

Comment: git somehow seems to be unable to call the tool `less`. Can you call it from the terminal? Just type `less path/to/file` (with a path to a valid file) and see if you can watch that file. You can quit less by pressing `q`. Did `git diff` work before?

Comment: Can you post the output of `git config -l | grep core.pager && echo "pager evn.: '$GIT_PAGER'"` from within your Git repository where the command shows the error please?

Comment: @lucash I just tried that and it responded: `-bash: less: command not found`. `git diff` worked before. The only thing I changed was tried to make Sublime Text 2 open when I typed `git commit`. Not sure what I accidentally messed up while doing that

Comment: @Vampire it says: `-bash: grep: command not found`

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant, but when I type `git status`, it says: `On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean`

Comment: @AKarl no, it is not. Ok, then try again with `git config core.pager && echo "pager evn.: '$GIT_PAGER'"` and also try simply running `less` please

Comment: The output of `echo $PATH` would also be interesting.

Comment: When I type `less` I get `-bash: less: command not found`

Comment: And when I type `echo $PATH` I get `/usr/local/bin::/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin`

Comment: @lucash @Vampire So when I type `git config core.pager && echo "pager evn.: '$GIT_PAGER'"` I get `less -r pager evn.: ''`

Comment: Try opening a new terminal and see if it works there. If it does not, open the file .bash_profile in your home directory and search for a line which starts with `PATH=` and show us that line. It seems that your PATH is messed up somehow so the bash can not find the commands.

Comment: @lucash that fixed it! I had `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATHc` in my .bash_profile from the advice of someone to make Sublime Text the default program to open with git commit and subl. I got rid of that and now git diff works.

Comment: Now sublime text opens when I type `subl` but if I try to add a commit I get this: `Sublime Text 2: Sublime: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'Sublime Text 2'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.` How do I fix it?

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you so much for your help!!